# HTML nesting in sitecore

Tags: sitecore

When I use an unordered list as mentioned below in the rich text field editor in sitecore and save it:

```
&lt;ul&gt;
&lt;li&gt;one&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;two
&lt;ul&gt;
&lt;li&gt;alpha&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;beta&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;theta&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;/ul&gt; 
&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;three&lt;/li&gt; 
&lt;/ul&gt;
```

It translates to something like :-

```
ul
    li one /li
    li two /li
    ul  /ul
    li alpha /li
    li beta /li
    li theta /li
    li three /li
/ul
```

Please provide ways or technique to properly create a nested list of menu in Rich Text Editor.

Comment: https://markstiles.net/Blog/2011/03/15/rich-text-editor-profiles.aspx or if you want rich text to keep all html tags in place http://laubplusco.net/customizing-sitecore-rich-text-field-configuration/

Comment: I assume that you are not confused between design mode and HTML mode in rich text field.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

I have used Sitecore version 8, standard Rich text editor that comes with installation and tested it in Firefox and Chrome browser, both seems to work fine, see the attached results.

Please mention your Sitecore version and Browser name/version.

As a best practise to create menus, I would suggest to use foreach loops within your renderings, displaying sitecore items with ul/li blocks around them.

Thanks
Naveed

Comment: Hi Naveed. Thanks for answering. When we provide the above html script the desired output must be some thing like :-

.) one
.) two
      .)alpha
      .)beta
.)theta
.)three.

Alpha and beta must be included under two but they are now coming outside two.

Comment: Can you upload a screen shot please ?

Comment: I was unable to add a screen shot in the comment so I posted it as an answer. Please refer to that screen shot.